# How to set a operating path?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, system.io.file

```
namespace Videos_umbennen
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string path = @"C:\Users\Kamil\Desktop\C# with .Net Programming\";
            var myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.mp4");
            for (int i = 0; i < myFiles.Length; i++)
            {

                File.Move(Path.GetFileName(myFiles[i]), "video " + i);

            }
            var newFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.mp4");
            for (int i = 0; i < newFiles.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(newFiles.GetValue(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote this code but the problem is that it works only in the folder where I put the program's `.exe`, so how do I make the `.exe` work from any directory? Is there some Method or something with which I can indicate that I work in a specificated path or something?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. This code should work whatever the path of the .exe is. What would be constant is the path where it would find and move the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on where you want to move them. Currently you just place them in the path where the EXE is running because you do not specify a folder so that is the default.

Example:

```
File.Move(myFiles[i], Path.Combine(path, "video " + i.ToString + ".mp4"));

// Path.GetFileName is not necessary, the path returned from GetFiles is the full path
```

That would move the file to the same directory but change the file name to `video XXX.mp4`

In short though do not try to change the "operating path" (*as stated in your question title*), instead specify exactly where you want the file to be moved to, read from, or whatever. Do not make any assumptions as to what directory you are working from unless everything is assumed to be rooted from the application directory (*only makes sense for operations like logging to a file, retrieving an application deployed resource, etc*)

Comment: Even when logging to a file, you should choose a proper AppData path.  The user running SomeApp shouldn't need write permission to `C:\Program Files\SomeApp` for logging to work.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is this line:

```
File.Move(Path.GetFileName(myFiles[i]), "video " + i);
```

The second argument `"video " + i` is going to be relative to the currently executing program.  You can make it relative to `path` by using `Path.Combine`

```
File.Move(Path.GetFileName(myFiles[i]), Path.Combine(path, "video " + i));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can  `Server.MapPath("C:\Users\Kamil\Desktop\C# with .Net Programming\")` it returns the complete path, including the directory on the server.

Comment: `Server.MapPath` works only on web applications. The question is abou Console applications. The OP isn't asking how to find the current path anyway, but how to *move* files to a specific path